# Tikz-datavisualisation custom tik labels

Tags: tikz-datavisualization

I am trying to create a graph, where the labels for the tikz mark are not supposed to be numbers but strings, is there a(n easy) way to achieve this with tikz-datavisualisation?

Mockup of what I am going for:
[image]

Notice that the tikz are labeled with names. A further issue I don"t know how to fix is how to set marks ONLY where I supply data.

Exampledata I supply:

```
alpha 2 3
hotel 3 6
uniform 1 7
```

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     %input encoding
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}  
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclaredataformat{cacheConfigs}%
{}{}{#1 #2 #3}
{%
    \pgfkeys{/data point/.cd, x=#1, y=#2, set=1} \pgfdatapoint
    \pgfkeys{/data point/.cd, x=#1, y=#3, set=2} \pgfdatapoint
}{}{}

\datavisualization [scientific axes=clean, %y axis=grid,
style sheet=vary dashing,
visualize as line/.list={1,2}]
data[format=cacheConfigs] {
1 2 3
2 3 6
3 1 7
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide a minimal example document that shows how you want to provide the data?

Comment: @Jake: I hope the picture/mwe helps if there is anything else to make the question clearer let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's one way to do this: We can store the labels in a list macro and assign the data points an x value based on a simple counter. For printing the labels, we then pick out the corresponding list entry for a given x position. To have only tick marks where we also have data, you can set `x axis={ticks={step=1}}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\def\ticksfromlabellist#1{%
    \pgfmathparse{{\label@list}[#1]}%
    \pgfmathresult%
}

\pgfdeclaredataformat{cacheConfigs}%
{} % No catcode changes
{\@tempcnta=1 \xdef\label@list{}} % Initialise count and label list
{#1 #2 #3}  % Argument format
{%
    \xdef\label@list{\label@list,"#1"}  % Append label to list
    \pgfkeys{/data point/.cd, x=\the\@tempcnta, y=#2, set=1} \pgfdatapoint  % Store data point, with count as x
    \pgfkeys{/data point/.cd, x=\the\@tempcnta, y=#3, set=2} \pgfdatapoint
    \advance\@tempcnta 1\relax  % Step the count
}{}{}
\makeatother

\datavisualization [
    scientific axes=clean,
    style sheet=vary dashing,
    visualize as line/.list={1,2},
    x axis={
        ticks={
            step=1,
            tick typesetter/.code=\ticksfromlabellist{##1},
            style={text height=1ex} % For proper vertical alignment
        }
    }
] data [format=cacheConfigs] {
a 2 3
b 3 6
c 1 7
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```